# Java and Android: Getting a substring from a string

Tags: java, android

I get a Json format data in android and I combine them and store in String like that. Now I want only particular strings.

```
$String outPut = "Doc Name: "+name + "\nRoom No: " + number+ "\nTime:"+time;
Doc Name: John 
Room No: 12 
Time: 09:00:00
```

I want to get only "John" and "12" and "09:00:00".

Comment: String time = jsonobject.getString("Time");

Comment: @SURESH ATTS how i use Json praser i have store the date in list as and now i want to get only the name time and room no to send to next activity.

Comment: @ArshadParwez could you kindly explain little bit more so that i get the exact idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] parts = outPut.split(":");
System.out.println(parts[1]);//prints John
System.out.println(parts[3]);//prints 12
System.out.println(parts[5]+":"+parts[6]+":"+parts[7]);//prints 09:00:00
```

Comment: i have printed only `parts[1]` but it show an error **java.lang.ArrayIndexoutofbounf**